# Detect when removable storage is unmounted

Tags: cocoa, volume, removable-storage, nsworkspace, diskarbitration

I am working on an app which should detect events that happen when removable storage is unmounted or forcefully unplugged from the USB. How can I receive these events?

I have seen `NSWorkspace` for the first possibility of smoothly unmounting the device but this class has methods like `-unmountAndEjectDeviceAtPath:` to unmount a device. Can someone point me to some sample code that detects unmounted volumes?

Answer (score 10):

A pice of code from HardwareGrowler:

```
NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSNotificationCenter *center = [workspace notificationCenter];

[center addObserver:[VolumeNotifier class] selector:@selector(volumeDidMount:) name:NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification object:nil];
[center addObserver:[VolumeNotifier class] selector:@selector(volumeDidUnmount:) name:NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification object:nil];
[center addObserver:[VolumeNotifier class] selector:@selector(volumeWillUnmount:) name:NSWorkspaceWillUnmountNotification object:nil];
```

You then need to implement the methods to react on the notifications ala

```
+ (void) volumeDidUnmount:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
{
...
}
```

For the whole implementation check out http://growl.info/source.php
In the Source bundle go to Extras/HardwareGrowler and there check out `VolumeNotifier.h/m`

**UPDATE:**

Peters answer is superior to this. Please consider using the Disk Arbitration framework if you come about this problem.

Comment: Man, and I work on HardwareGrowler! I would not make those class methods, though. Someday, when other things aren't so pressing, I intend to go through and change the notifiers to instances (among other clean-ups).

Comment: Make sure to make it a background app as well ;)

Answer (score 7):

Use [the `DARegisterDiskDisappearedCallback` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/DiskArbitration_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/DARegisterDiskDisappearedCallback) in [the Disk Arbitration framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/).

Comment: It is described in Amit Singh's book "Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach" too.

Comment: Documentation can now be found at http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/

Comment: @QuinnTaylor: Documentation links added. Thanks!

Comment: @PacMan--: Sort of. There are certain non-trivial cases in which a volume can be unmounted without disappearing (particularly when it's not the only volume on that disk). You also want DescriptionChanged; a volume whose disk description doesn't have a mount path is not mounted.

Comment: Absolutely. I'd like to rephrase my comment: Using the Disk Arbitration framework would probably be the correct way to do it; it gives you many possibilities, when comparing to other solutions. (as for myself, I just used the DA framework and I supply a matchDictionary, so I filter out most harddisks - eg. matching for "DADeviceProtocol" = "USB" and "DAMediaRemovable" = 1)